# How to subtract the value of two cells if vlookup matches on two other cells in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

Formula to compare B3 in sheet 1 to column A in sheet 2 (Defined Range Name - COUNTY).  If they match then subtract the value of A3 from D2 OR compare C3 in sheet 1 to column A in sheet 2 (Defined Range Name - COUNTY).  If they match then add the value of A3 to D2.  This is what I have now and it is not adding or subtracting.  It just carries down the previous total.

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(OR(VLOOKUP($B3,COUNTY),D2-$A3,OR(VLOOKUP($C3,COUNTY),D2+$A3))),D2)
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using `MATCH` combined with an `ISERROR` function.
In cell `D3`, write the following formula:

```
=D2 - IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B3,COUNTY,0)),0,A3) + IF(ISERROR(MATCH(C3,COUNTY,0)),0,A3)
```

You can copy this down in column D.

The way this works is that it starts with `D2`, then subtracts, using an `IF`/`ISERROR`:

- By `0` (defined in formula), if `U2` (cell B3) **isn't** in the range `COUNTY` because `ISERROR` would return `TRUE`
- By `4` (cell A3), if `U2` (cell B3) **is** in the range `COUNTY`, because `ISERROR` would return `FALSE`

The second part of the formula works the same way, but with an addition instead.

You can check references for the functions used here:

- [ISERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093349?hl=en)
- [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

you were close, but all your formulas after `IFERROR` are all wrong/incomplete. paste this into **D3** cell and drag down:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(B3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, County)), D2-A3, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(C3, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, County)), D2+A3, D2))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: LOL!!  Close?!?!?  I wasn't close at all after looking at your formula!!!   That worked great!  Thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: just me being polite :)